# Finding an $\mathbb R$-representation for $M^*.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, matroids, algebraic-combinatorics

Here is something I want to learn ( Problem #2.2.7 in Matroid Theory, first edition( page 88 ) , by James Oxley:

Finding an $\mathbb R$-representation for the dual matroid $M^*$ when $M$ is the vector matroid of the following matrix over $\mathbb R:$( sorry I was not able to type the matrix so I had to take a picture of it):

[image]

My questions are:

I know the following theorem:

**Theorem 2.2.8**

Let $M$ be the vector matroid of the matrix $[I_r | D]$ where the columns of this matrix are labelled, in order, $e_1, e_2, \dots , e_n$ and $1\leq r < n.$ Then $M^*$ is the vector matroid of $[ - D^T | I_{n-r} ]$ where its columns are also labelled $e_1, e_2, \dots , e_n$ in that order.

So I am guessing that the answer to this question is just to calculate $[ - D^T | I_{n-r} ],$ am I correct? But if so, the given matrix is not a square matrix( I do not know the number of rows of the matrix), so it is not very clear to me how to calculate $[ - D^T | I_{n-r} ],$ we can only find inverses of square matrices so I am confused now.

I tried to see the matrix for different $n$ values and here is what I came up with:

$n = 1,2$ the pattern cannot be satisfied. For $n=3,$ I do not know where exactly will be the $-1$ and what will be beside it.

Note that, in the second edition of "Matroid Theory" book by Oxley, the matrix was different and it sounds like it does not have a pattern like this in it, I suspect it is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by inverse? This is still a square matrix by construction. Call the matrix $A$. Notice that if we consider the rows of $A$, say $\{r_i\}_{i\in [n]}$, then for $1< i<n$ we have that $r_i = e_i+e_{i-1}$, $r_1 = e_1+e_n$ and $r_n = e_{n-1}+(-1)^ne_n$, where $e_j = (0,\cdots ,1,\cdots 0)$ has a $1$ exactly at position $j$ and has zeroes everywhere else.
We can apply row operations to this matrix and maintain the matroid, so  replace $r_2$ by $r_2-r_1=(e_2+e_{1})-(e_1+e_{n})=e_2-e_n$, and replace $r_3$ by $r_3-r_2=(e_3+e_{2})-(e_2-e_n)=e_3+e_n$ and notice that doing this for every row $r_i$ with $1\leq i<n$ you get $r_i = e_i+(-1)^{i-1}e_n$. Now row $r_n$ replace it with $r_n-r_{n-1}=(e_{n-1}+(-1)^ne_n)-(e_{n-1}+(-1)^{n}e_n)=0$. Erase the last row and you end up with the matrix
$$A = [I_{n-1}|D]$$ with $D = (1,-1,\cdots ,(-1)^n)^T$ and so, using the theorem you copied here, the representation of the dual is given by $$[-1,1,\cdots ,(-1)^{n+1}|I_1].$$

Comment: What is the main idea of solving problems like this? In the given matrix, How can I decide what is $I_r$ and what is $D$? and then what I am aiming for while I am row reducing the given matrix?

Comment: @Brain It is to find the dual matroid. Linear matroids are not changed by row reduction and the Thm that the OP has stated gives us a formula for the matrix that represents the dual. From here one can see that rank of the dual is 1 and that essentially this is a uniform matroid $U_{1,n}$

Comment: I do not see anything that said that $r=1$ in the OP question, could you clarify please why $r=1$?

Comment: The first step is trying to find an identity matix in the matrix given to us, am I correct?

Comment: It is not always true that the matrix representing a matroid is a square matrix, right? what construction said that the given matrix by the op is a square matrix?

Comment: @Brain Well, the rank of one vector is 1..so $r=1$. Yes, the first step is row reduction, which is finding that identity matrix. Yes, you can have matroids with non square matrix. In this case the matrix is square by just looking at the construction. You are moving those $11$ ones one column to the right at each step.